# Mongoose find can return all but not just one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

I am using mongoose in a express-graphQL app and I am having an issue where my `find({})` query returns as expected, but I cannot get my `find({id})` query to return anything except null. The top results for this kind of search on stack overflow will suggest that this is a pluralization issue on the model, and while that might be the case, I don't believe it is since I can get the find-all functionality working fine with the singular usage of my model. This query:

```
{
  books {
    id
  }
}
```

using this schema:

```
books: {
  type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
  resolve() {
    return Book.find({});
  }
}
```

returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
      },
      {
        "id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In contrast, this query returns `null` as the book value:

```
{
    book(id:"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011") {
    id
  }
}
```

where this is my schema definition:

```
book: {
  type: BookType,
  args: { id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) } },
  resolve(parentValue, { id }) {
    return Book.find({ id });
  }
},
```

When I console.log my id parameter in that resolve function, it returns the id as expected. I have tried using mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) as a way to force it as an id instead of a string, but that doesn't seem to help. This is what my model looks like, note I am not defining my id and in my actual database, the id field is entered as `_id` even though I call it by `id` in the query.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
});

mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema);
```

EDIT: After some more research, I have found that this findOne works:

```
Book.findOne({ name: "title" });
```

while either of these do not:

```
Book.findOne({ id: "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011" });
Book.findOne({ id });
```

This clearly points to some issue with how I am formatting my id query but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: should be `Book.findById(id);`

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When creating sample documents in the database, it is really important how the _id parameter is formatted. I had it formatted as:

```
"_id": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
```

When in actuality, mongoose is looking for it to be formatted like this:

```
"_id": {
    "$oid": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
},
```

Simply swapping those two in the database fixed it immediately!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your implementation, but here's what to watch for when writing a line like this:

```
return Book.find({ id });
```

1. In the curly braces as already noted, you need to describe the key and value, not just the key e.g.

   { id: "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011" }
2. Ensure they key matches what you have in the system e.g. _id or id
3. The value may be represented as a string or an ObjectId..use ObjectId to convert from string as necessary (not sure if mongoose is forgiving about this, but mongodb native driver is not. I believe the best practice ought to be to store all values as ObjectIds and convert strings to ObjectId on all queries).
4. Be careful about code that relies on find vs findOne...the first will return an array (even if it's an array of one object). The code that consumes the result (e.g. client-side) likely expects one or the other, so it may appear that the find / findOne query fails when the problem is really with parsing the data.